# Unable to use property of youtube player after importing into another module

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, amd

I created a class of youtube api because I need it in multiple files but when I trying to access the getPlayerState() then its giving me error of that it is not a function but when I console.log
I see in the list getPlayerState(). below is the code of my youTubeManager.js

```
   // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars

class YouTubeManager {
    constructor() {
        this.player = null;
        this.playerState = null;
        this.readyPromise = this.initYouTubeAPI();
    }

    initYouTubeAPI() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Initialize YouTube API
            window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => {
                this.createPlayer();
                resolve();
            };

            const tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
            tag.onerror = () => reject(Error('Error loading YouTube API'));
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(tag);
        });
    }

    createPlayer() {
        // Create the YouTube player
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        this.player = new YT.Player('another-love', {
            events: {
                'onStateChange': this.onPlayerStateChange.bind(this)
            }
        });
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
            if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
               State = event.data;
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                console.log("video is playing");
            } else if (event.data === 2) {
                State = event.data;
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                console.log("video is paused");
            }
        }
}
const youtubeManager = new YouTubeManager();
export default youtubeManager;
```

---

In here I am calling it but I am trying to access the playerState. its giving me error

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
define(['jquery', './youTubeManager'], function($, youtubeManager)
{
    youtubeManager.readyPromise.then(() => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        const player = youtubeManager.player; // Access the player from the instance;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(youtubeManager);
    }).catch(error => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.error(error.message);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're trying to access `playerState` as a function, but it's actually a property. You should access it like this:

```
const playerState = youtubeManager.player.getPlayerState();
```

**Full Code:**

```
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
define(['jquery', './youTubeManager'], function($, youtubeManager) {
    youtubeManager.readyPromise.then(() => {
        // Access the player from the instance
        const player = youtubeManager.player;

        // Access the playerState property
        const playerState = player.getPlayerState();

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(playerState);
    }).catch(error => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.error(error.message);
    });
});
```

Comment: first.js:3252  youtubeManager.player.getPlayerState is not a function

I tried in this way but I am able to find a solution by attaching eventListener

Answer (score 0):

I simply attach the EventListener now its giving me the event.state which that I can figure out current state below is the correct code

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
define(['jquery', './youTubeManager'], function($, youtubeManager)
{
    youtubeManager.readyPromise.then(() => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        const player = youtubeManager.player; // Access the player from the instance;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        youtubeManager.player.addEventListener('onStateChange', (event) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log(event.data);
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.error(error.message);
    });
});
```